# Locating local directory for localhost

Tags: wordpress, directory, xampp, localhost, local

I've been spending hours trying to locate where localhost's files are stored.
I've tried looking at the page source but all it tells me is http:/localhost/....
which is not what I need.
My Xampp directory (where I load Xampp control) is located in my desktop but there is no change when I alter stuff inside its htdocs.

Comment: Tell me about your Operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The default root for XAMPP, assuming you installed in the default location, is `c:\xampp\htdocs`. You can change this by modifying the Apache configuration in `c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`.

Comment: I did not install it in the default location.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check it through PHP:

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

Or if you want to use WordPress functions:

```
echo get_stylesheet_directory();
```

Include these codes in your page.php or header.php for example.

Comment: I can't change the files if I don't know the directory (unless there is a way idk about)